# Splitting string separated by / - ; - from one record into many unique records

Tags: sql

I have a 1 column SQL table with 3 rows of product numbers separated by special characters

```
/ ; - ,
```

Row 1 has value `62200; 62251 / 62201`.

How can I split these products numbers into individual records so that the record above will become 3 records like:

```
62200
62251
62201
```

I will also like to keep the original column for mapping purposes.  Hopefully something like this:

```
62200; 62251 / 62201        62200
62200; 62251 / 62201        62251
62200; 62251 / 62201        62201
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using, SQL Server? Oracle? Please specify as they all have slightly different built in functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server...

Take a look at the CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions. Below is an example of how to split it out, I would suggest adjusting it to handle cases when the sought special character is not found. You might also need to TRIM the results to get rid of whitespace if you want to store your new values as numerics of some sort.

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT, @delimiter CHAR(1), 
    SET @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = [string to split goes here!]
    SET @delimiter = ';'
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    INSERT INTO TABLE (fullstring, splitdata)  
    VALUES(@string, TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))) 
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @delimiter = ';'
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    INSERT INTO TABLE (fullstring, splitdata)  
    VALUES(@string, TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)))
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @delimiter = '/'
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    INSERT INTO TABLE (fullstring, splitdata)  
    VALUES(@string, TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)))
END
```

You could also try to tackle this with regex, which might be a little less code-heavy. Also, for the sake of not burying yourself in repetitive code, I would extract that 'SPLIT' behavior off to its own function.

The equivalent functions in Oracle  are INSTR and SUBSTR, if that is what you are using.
[Credit for the example](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/)